# Definition of standard error in scipy.stats.linregress

Tags: python, scipy

I'm using the [scipy.stats.linregress](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.15.1/reference/generated/scipy.stats.linregress.html) function to do a simple linear regression on some 2D data, e.g.:

```
from scipy import stats
x = [5.05, 6.75, 3.21, 2.66]
y = [1.65, 26.5, -5.93, 7.96]
gradient, intercept, r_value, p_value, std_err = stats.linregress(x,y)
```

The documentation on the function states that `std_err` is the:

> Standard error of the estimate

I'm not sure what this means. This [old answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2038870/1391441) says that it represents the "*standard error of the gradient line*" but that this "*was not always the behaviour of this library*".

Could I get a precise definition of what exactly this parameter represent?

Comment: This is a standard measure in statistics. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ordinary_least_squares#Finite_sample_properties for a description of how to compute it. In simple terms it tells you how good of a fit the gradient is (higher values mean less precise) for your data.

Comment: @JamesPringle would you mind posting your comment as an answer so I can accept it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a standard measure in statistics. See [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ordinary_least_squares#Finite_sample_properties) for a description of how to compute it. Unfortunately, stackoverflow does not seem to have LaTeX support, so it does not make sense to write out and explain the equations here.

Essentially, `std_err` should give a value for each coefficient represented in the gradient. In simple terms `std_err` tells you how good of a fit the gradient is (higher values mean less precise) for your data.

Other useful answers on stats.stackexchange sites are [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/131431/best-ols-estimators/131461#131461) and [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/93303/variance-covariance-matrix-interpretation/93311#93311).

Answer (score 6):

As of Dec 2016, I think that it's still showing the standard error of the slope of the OLS regression line. I calculated the regression of some datasets using [orthogonal distance regression](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/odr.html) as part of the scipy package, and [the output's](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.odr.Output.html#scipy.odr.Output) `sd_beta[1]` (representative of the standard error of the slope of the regression line) was very similar to the `std_err` as calculated by [scipy.stats.linregress](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.15.1/reference/generated/scipy.stats.linregress.html).